# Ember App.Object.find() doesn't work but this.store.find('object') works

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model Post, and its relevant controller and route. In PostsRoute, I have:

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('post');
    },
})
```

This works fine. However,

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Post.find();
    },
})
```

Yields this error:

```
 Error while processing route: posts.index undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at App.PostsRoute.Ember.Route.extend.model (http://localhost:3000/assets/routes/posts_route.js?body=1:4:25)
...
```

I suspect that this might affect the way this data can be accessed from another controller (which is ultimately what I want to do, but I would very much like to know why App.Post.find() does not work.

Comment: Are you referencing an old tutorial? The version that works is the one you should be using. The other was removed a long time ago.

Comment: Oh my. I was, indeed, following a tutorial. Well, in that case i shall close this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to share data between controllers you can use "needs" property.
So if you need your post controller and your in another controller you can use dependencies.

```js
App.SomeOtherController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: "post"
});
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

Comment: I used this with the this.store.find() approach for sure. Turns out I was following an old tutorial so trying to access Post.find.all was not the way to go anyway.